# Different filters in view for each product page

Tags: 7, views

Working in drupal 7.

Im not sure how to do this actually, but i have a big view with a lot of products and a long list of filters were you can search the product.

But lets say i want to go to cars page, then the filters from all the others products is still there, how can i hide those filters from that particular page? So it don´t affects the "see all" page where all the filters should be.

It´s made in one view which is called search-products, and that view is in all the pages.

Under advanced i have added taxonomy term with depths. And also have the better exposed filters installed, i´ve tried to hide some filters under BEF settings and only for this page, but didn´t work, it also hides it in the "all page".

Comment: You need to use search API + facets. That will give you filters that only apply to the current result set

Comment: or just hide the filters you don't want on a certain page with css